# No Style in Pages of MVC 4 with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

After creating a blank MVC 4 project in VS 2010 on Windows 7, I did following to install Bootstrap packages

```
Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4
Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample
```

When I ran the project, everything compiled but the pages had no style at all unlike what [the package site](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2012/11/20/twitter-bootstrap-mvc4-the-template-nuget-package-for-asp-net-mvc4-projects/) suggested. Is this normal or did I need to do any additional thing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like that's the empty MVC4 application.  It looks like that's the Internet application template, which will already have a default page.  Looks like that default page is being loaded - and it doesn't have any HTML to use the bootstrap classes.

Try again with the Empty MVC4 application template, it should work then  (I just tried it in VS2012 and it worked, at least.)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. After working with ASP.NET MVC for last three years, I didn't know what "Empty" MVC project really was.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem here. But I already created a empty MVC4 project.