# Unable to get Twitter.Bootstrap.Mvc4.sample working in empty MVC4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I've installed Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC4 into an Asp.Net MVC Empty project template and when I start the application there are issues with the style sheets. It looks to me like they aren't linked in. Screen grab below.

[image: Bootstrap.MVC4 output]

And the head section is below

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/content/css?v=o7EqNjjD8FotmTy6On6adamUxH559LswOFRclfNrDPM1" rel="stylesheet"/>

       <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="/scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


</head>
```

Comment: Click f12 in google chrome and go to the Network panel.  Look for the sylesheet and correct the path accordingly.

Comment: Right, the network tab is only showing the style sheet shown above (/content/css?v=o7EqNjjD8FotmTy6On6adamUxH559LswOFRclfNrDPM1). I was expecting that the nuget package would take care of setting the correct style sheets for me as that seems like the whole point.

Comment: You will have to figure out how to get your stylesheets in there, I guess.

Comment: OK so one of us doesn't understand what Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC4 is because if my understanding is correct then your comment is confusing.

Comment: That's probably me.  I have never used it.  All I know is, you gotta get your stylesheets on the page for them to work :)  good luck

Comment: No worries and much appreciated your time on this. Basically Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC4 will create a ASP.Net MVC 4 application which will generate CRUD admin pages for you based on your models that are styled using Twitter Bootstrap. They are supposed to save you from having to deal with all the styling concerns and let you focus on cranking out BL.

Comment: Have you seen these answers?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533591/why-are-my-style-bundles-not-rendering-correctly-in-asp-net-mvc-4 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792963/no-style-in-pages-of-mvc-4-with-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the BootstrapBundleConfig.cs file, there is a path error.

"~/Content/bootstrap.css" should be "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"

bootstrap-responsive.css is also missing.

Have fun ;-)

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks for posting. There are other files in that folder. Anyone know if they needed?

Comment: Waheed Khan's solution is better, move css files from ~/Content/bootstrap to ~/Content.

Comment: Please pray tell, why is it better to move the css files than to change the path in the bundle config?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem, this happens because when you install nuget package it installs the latest bootstrap which is now 3.0, while Twitter.Bootstrap.Mvc4.sample has configured itself for 2.x.

If you don't need 3.0, than you can download 2.x version and copy scripts and content in their respective folders.

For 3.0 move css files from ~/Content/bootstrap to ~/Content.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a sample project illustrating ASP.NET MVC with Twitter Bootstrap, you can download visual studio 2013 preview for Web and create a new MVC project. Bootstrap is available in MVC template. New addition to MVC 5. This template will enable you to see the folder structure and make the necessary adjustments in the above project.